# how to save matrix with type *.mat then load it in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, mat

how to save matrix with extension .mat for example I've this matrix :

```
x = round (100*rand(4,4))
```

I want to save x matrix in file x.mat then load it which can access element of this matrix, I tried by loading x.matrix but it was gave me struct 1X1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save 'x.mat';` or `save x;` command will do the saving

`load 'x.mat';` or `load x;` will get back the matrix `x` in your workspace

```
data_cell = struct2cell(load('x.mat'));
data = data_cell{1};
```

or if you are sure only one matrix in `x.mat`:

```
data = struct2array(load('x.mat'));
```

Comment: `load x.mat`? See `doc save`.

Comment: y = load ('x.mat') but y is struct 1X1 I want to access element of x

Comment: @sarot Is this what you need?